# BigQuery DateTime Extraction Query on Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have this where clause in BigQuery's query and it works fine when used on console.

> DATE(TIMESTAMP) >= DATE_SUB(current_date() , INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND DATE(TIMESTAMP) < DATE_SUB(current_date() , INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND EXTRACT(hour from timestamp(TIMESTAMP)) >= EXTRACT(hour from timestamp(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME() , INTERVAL 8 DAY))) AND EXTRACT(hour from timestamp(TIMESTAMP)) < EXTRACT(hour from timestamp(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME() , INTERVAL 8 DAY) + INTERVAL 4 HOUR))

But when I am using the same in Apache Beam then it gives me the error

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: request failed: Query error: No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP for argument types: TIMESTAMP. Supported signatures: TIMESTAMP(STRING, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(DATE, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(DATETIME, [STRING]) at [1:498]

Code that is used to make a call to BQ is

```
BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
.from(queryConditions.tableName())                          
.withRowRestriction(queryConditions.queryRestriction())                                     
.withMethod(BigQueryIO.TypedRead.Method.DIRECT_READ)
.withSelectedFields(ROW.SELECTED_FIELDS))
```

Beam SDK Version : `2.51.0`

Java Version : `17`

Library Used : `org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.51.0`

Comment: Looks like a BigQuery issue. Are you sure you apply it to the exact same data when running the query on the console? As the error states, it looks like as if your `TIMESTAMP` column contains something of the [BigQuery type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type) `TIMESTAMP` which is not supported by the [timestamp function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp).